# How to make POST requests to save a list of objects sequentially in angular 4/5

Tags: angular, web-services, observable

How can I approach following problem in angular 4/5?

I have a list of objects which are related by `parentId`, for example

```
[
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Parent Unit",
    parentId: null,  
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: "Unit Child 1",
    parentId: 10,  
  }, 
  {
    id: 12,
    name: "Unit Child 2",
    parentId: 10,  
  } 
]
```

I need to save them through web service by calling POST method three times. The requirement is that I have to save them synchronously. I mean, I have to wait until `Parent Unit` is saved, the web service returns its new `id` and then I can make another POST request with modified `parentId` for `Unit Child 1` to web service and the similar request with modified `parentId` for `Unit Child 2`.

I use `Observables` for making web services in my angular app. Any ideas how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean "sequentially" :)

First problem is that your data structure is not really suited for this use case. I think it would be better to have hierarchical structure, not flat one. But if it has to stay, then I would implement it like this. If you refactor your datastructure, then the code for saving could be nicer..

```
// pseudo code

 save() {
 // first request
 let promise = httpService.post('someurl', parentObject)
    .then(() => {
      // second request for children
      return httpService.post('someurl', childObject);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a new issue for the hierarchical structure as you suggested as a better approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450617/how-to-make-post-requests-to-save-a-list-of-objects-in-the-hierarchical-structur

Answer (score 0):

Chain them:

Assuming you use Angular's `HttpClient`:

```
const http = new HttpClient();

const result = http.post(urlService, item1)
  .flatMap(result => http.post(urlService, item2))
  .flatMap(result => http.post(urlService, item3));
```

Then, by subscribing to `result` you can know when the three operations have finished or if there has been an error. Of course, in each flatMap you could also do something withe `result`, the response from the server, or just ignore it.

Now, if you want a way to chain N calls, you can define a function like:

```
chainPost(request: Observable<any>, url: string, item: any): Observable<any> {
    return request ? request.flatMap(() => http.post(url, item))
                   : http.post(url, item);
}
```

As you see, it takes the observable from a previous request and chains the new one to it. If there is no previous request (it is `null` or `undefined`), it returns directly the observable returned by `HttpClient.post`. Then you use it like this:

```
const requests: any[]  = [{...},{...}, ...]; // any number of items
const request = requests.reduce((previous, item) => chainPost(previous, url, item));
```

Now you can subscribe to the `request` observable and wait for it to finish or throw an error.

Of course, here I used `any` both for the data being sent and returned by the service, because I don't know if you have custom types or interfaces, but, any way, you can change that to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm considering if the reduce method should have an init property. In your example it does not have and I think `previous` argument becomes as first item from the requests array which it's not type of Observable<any>. Am I right?

Comment: the `previous` parameter in `reduce` has the value returned from the previous iteration. In this case I didn't initialise it, because, by making it `undefined` in the first call, `chainPost` just returns the first request. I'm assuming, of course, that you are posting just the array. If you have already a request ongoing, you may pass the returned observable to `reduce` and the requests from the array will be chained.