# How to make POST requests to save a list of objects in the hierarchical structure in angular

Tags: angular, observable, sequential

I have a list of objects in the hierarchical structure which are related by parentId, for example:

```
[
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Parent Unit 1",
    parentId: null, 
    children: 
    [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "Unit Child 1.1",
        parentId: 10,
        children:
        [
          {
            id: 15,
            name: "Unit Child 1.1.1",
            parentId: 11,
            children: []
        ]   
      }, 
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "Unit Child 1.2",
        parentId: 10,  
        children: []
      }
    ]   
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: "Parent Unit 2",
    parentId: null, 
    children: 
    [
      {
        id: 14,
        name: "Unit Child 2.2",
        parentId: 13,
        children: []  
      }
    ]
]
```

I need to save objects one by one through web service by calling POST method six times. The requirement is that I have to save them sequentially. I mean, I have to wait until Parent Unit is saved, when the web service returns new id of the parent object and then I can make another POST request to web service with modified parentId for `Unit Child` objects.

I use Observables for making web services in my angular app. Any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: Actually it would be better to send the whole data at once, and then let server handle it. Otherwise you will face complexity when dealing with failed requests. What should happen when one of the requests fails? Should you fire all again? How the server responds when data already exists?

Comment: Sorry that I did not point it out under the original question

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Your description makes sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap`

Here's a basic example of how it works

```
Rx.Observable.of('some_url')
  .switchMap(url => this.http.get(url))
```

Basically, you get the first id, switchmap it to use it on the 2nd call etc...

Read more about it here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html